# После чтения данных через командную строку блокируются любые манипуляции: чтения и записи в файл

Tags: c++

Есть простой пример. Я открываю командную строку cmd, ввожу путь к *.exe и имя текстового документа: C:\Windows\system32>"...exe" "in1.txt". На выходе получаю
first
Hello!
А second'a нет!
Проблема именно в считывании через командную строку, если эту манипуляцию убрать, то second прекрасно выводится.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void first(string& s1,ifstream& in) {
    in >> s1;                 // тут считывается файл со строкой first
    in.close();
}
void second(string& s2) {
    ifstream in2("in2.txt");    //тут записано second
    in2 >> s2;
    in2.close();
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) { cerr << "\nError.";exit(-1); }
    ifstream in(argv[1]);

    string s1,s2;
    first(s1, in);      //in.close();
    second(s2);

    cout << s1<<endl;
    cout << "Hello!"<<endl;
    cout<< s2;

    system("pause>void");
    return 0;
}
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: А зачем вы записываете результат команды `pause` в файл `void`?

Comment: Просто освойте хорошую практику: всегда проверять ошибки при работе с файлами и выводить подробную диагностику если что-то не так. И научитесь пользоваться отладчиком. 99% вопросов, подобных этому, сразу отпадут.

Comment: Что тут гадать: second-а нет, потому что у вас нет файла `in2.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Работает как задумано, если в командной строке предварительно перейти в папку с программой и её файлами.

Или указывать полные пути к файлам — как в тексте программы, так и в консоли.